Reducing gap between bars of bar chart in R
I wrote the following code for plotting bar charts :
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

interaction_data <- read.csv("association.tsv")

interaction_data <- interaction_data %>%
  mutate(interaction_type = case_when(
    v1 == 'Bacteria' & v2 == 'Bacteria' ~ 'Bacteria-Bacteria',
    (v1 == 'Bacteria' & v2 == 'Archaea') | (v1 == 'Archaea' & v2 == 'Bacteria') ~ 'Bacteria-Archaea',
    v1 == 'Archaea' & v2 == 'Archaea' ~ 'Archaea-Archaea'
  ),
  interaction_sign = ifelse(asso > 0, 'Positive', 'Negative'))

# Calculate the count of positive and negative interactions for each interaction type
interaction_counts <- interaction_data %>%
  group_by(interaction_type, interaction_sign) %>%
  summarise(count = n())

# Plot the stacked bar plot with the number of interactions and no grid lines
ggplot(interaction_counts, aes(x = interaction_type, y = count, fill = interaction_sign)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = position_dodge(width = 0.5), width = 0.5) +  # Set width to 0.5 to make bars narrower
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Positive" = "hotpink2", "Negative" = "royalblue3")) +
  labs(x = '', y = 'Number of Interactions',
       fill = 'Interaction type') +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 14),
        axis.text = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 10),
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),  
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())  


I want to reduce the gap between bars. They are very placed very far.
this is how my graph looks like:

I need some help with adjusting the spacing of the whole diagram.

Please use proper terminology: A histogram is a specific type of barplot and yours isn't a histogram. Also, provide data for a reproducible example.

You specify width = 0.5 and that controls how wide the bar are. It sounds like you want them wider, so that the space between them will be smaller.

Just put position = position_dodge(). Don't mess with the default widths unless they look bad, Your's are fine.

Don't include the widths in position_dodge().
ggplot(interaction_counts, aes(x = interaction_type, y = n, fill = interaction_sign)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity' , position = position_dodge()) +
...



interaction_counts <- structure(list(interaction_type = c("Archaea-Archaea", "Bacteria-Archaea", 
"Bacteria-Archaea", "Bacteria-Bacteria", "Bacteria-Bacteria"), 
    interaction_sign = c("Negative", "Negative", "Positive", 
    "Negative", "Positive"), count = c(20L, 20L, 15L, 80L, 400L
    )), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), groups = structure(list(interaction_type = c("Archaea-Archaea", 
"Bacteria-Archaea", "Bacteria-Archaea", "Bacteria-Bacteria", 
"Bacteria-Bacteria"), interaction_sign = c("Negative", "Negative", 
"Positive", "Negative", "Positive"), .rows = structure(list(1L, 
    2L, 3L, 4L, 5L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .drop = TRUE))

